# TermQuery with a List by using Elasticsearch Java

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have my object Apk and in it a list of tag

```
private Set<String> tag = new HashSet<>();
```

I'm trying to query all games that match the tags. I tried many solutions but it is not working as expected.

```
List<String> tags;
tags.add("madeinafrica");

BoolQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
tags.forEach(tag-> qb.should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("tags", tag)));
qb.minimumShouldMatch(1);
        
// we initialise the native search
NativeSearchQueryBuilder nativeSearch  = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
      .withQuery(qb)
      .withPageable(PageRequest.of(page, size));
```

I tried also this solution

```
TermQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.termQuery("tags", tags);
NativeSearchQueryBuilder nativeSearch  = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
          .withQuery(qb)
          .withPageable(PageRequest.of(page, size));
```

Still not working, it returns all data in elasticsearch.
Please how could i do ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try replace QueryBuilders.termQuery("tags", tags); to  QueryBuilders.termsQuery("tags", tags);

Comment: @rabbitbr, with termsQuery i get all data in the elasticsearch. It is not filtered.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal runnable example that reproduces this?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch, i don't know how to provide a minmal example without deploying an entire infrastructure.

Comment: Just a minimal Spring Boot application for example that expects Elasticsearch to run on localhost:8080.

Comment: do you want to match all the values from tag list to `tags` field ? So if list have `madeinafrica` and `madeinafrica_1` two values means that document will come in result if both values match in `tags` field.

Comment: @SagarPatel, i want to match only `madeinafrica`  in your example.